# Navigation Drawer and SurfaceView in fragment

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview, paint, navigation-drawer

I want to use SurfeceView to make simple painting app like MS Paint.
I created main activity with navigation drawer as toolbox for painting tools.
I assumed that user I can operate on many surfaces (pages) so I made for each page separate fragment with SurfaceView inside.

In main activity I made customized button to open drawer.
In fragment I set mSurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true) for SurfaveView and in SurfaceView mHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)

Fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<it.controls.PaintPageLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:background="#e0aa66cc"
    android:visibility="visible">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Sv"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="#ffff4444"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:minWidth="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/surface_fragment_debug_save" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/surface_fragment_debug_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="debug_info"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/surface_fragment_debug_save" />
</RelativeLayout>
<it.controls.PaintSurfaceView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/surface_fragment_surface"
    />
```

Main layout is almost standard template generated from Android Studio, expect that my app is full screen (doesn't have Toolbar)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">
   <!-- The main content view -->
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_coordinate_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    <!-- button to show left menu -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/toolbox_toggle_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/toolbox_show_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/toolbox_show_margin"
        android:contentDescription="@string/menu_show_hide_menu"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_black_48dp"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/toolbox_show_button_size"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/toolbox_show_button_size"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbox_new_page_button_border"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/menu_container"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent">
</FrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

When I coded that I made simple drawing mechanism to draw path in SurfaceView and there is a problem.

My problem is that after I draw path I would like to change color so I must open toolbox (drawer). After I open drawer I saw that path is painted ON drawer as on screen below.

[image]

What I made wrong? How to hide SurfaceView behind drawer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app has two distinct layers: the View UI layer, and the SurfaceView Surface layer.  One of them is entirely on top of the other.  You can't put one partially under the other.  You put the SurfaceView Surface on top, so it's in front of all of your Views.

You might be better off with a [custom View](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html), rather than a SurfaceView.  It'll mix in with your other Views, and for Canvas rendering it can be more efficient because it'll take advantage of hardware-accelerated rendering.

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanation. I read from your message that there is no chance to collaborate SurfaceView and Navigation drawer because both controls (views) must be on top on view hierarchy tree.So the SurfaceView is useless form me in this situation. I will follow your suggestion and migrate to custom view.